# Change the selection in the ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I add audio files to the `ListBox` by clicking on the `Button`. Then `OpenFileDialog` (the code below) works. I use the added files `ListBox` to play (the code below). I click on `button_play`. There is a problem. When I click on the `Button` for sorting using `listBox1.Sorted = true`. After sorting, the audio file that should be played is not played. The audio file that was in this place before sorting is played. That is, if all songs had a number, then after sorting only the names were changed, but the numbers have not changed. And when you click `button_play` is played by the number.

```
private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            label_load.Text = list_catalog.Items.Count.ToString();
        }

private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        if (list_catalog.Items.Contains(Vars.GetFileName(file)))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Vars.Files.Add(file);
            list_catalog.Items.Add(Vars.GetFileName(file));
            hello.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string current = Vars.Files[list_catalog.SelectedIndex];
                Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = list_catalog.SelectedIndex;
                BassLike.Play(current, BassLike.Volume);
                label_time1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
                label_time2.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream)).ToString();
                xrewind.Maximum = BassLike.GetTimeOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
                xrewind.Value = BassLike.GetPosOfStream(BassLike.Stream);
                timer1.Enabled = true;

        }
```

Comment: You need to link the filename index with the list item index. There are several ways but I'd create a class with pathname and song metadata as properties, then create a list with this class. When sorting you can use any of the properties of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work...

```
string current = list_catalog.SelectedItem as string;
Vars.CurrentTrackNumber = Vars.Files.IndexOf(current);
```